# How to check if nested arrays are ALL empty in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have something like below:

```
{
        "_id" : "1",
        "firstArray" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "11",
                        "secondArray" : [ ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "12",
                        "secondArray" : [ ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "13",
                        "secondArray" : [ { "type" : "somthing" } ] 
               }
        ]

},
{
        "_id" : "2",
        "firstArray" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "21",
                        "secondArray" : [ ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "22",
                        "secondArray" : [ ]
                }
        ]

}
```

I need a mongodb query to find documents which ALL of the nested secondArrays are empty? the query should return second document and not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

to solve that, we need to check size of arr2, but to enable that we need first to unwind arr1.

Please find below aggregation framework snippet which solves this problem,

```
db.pmoubed.aggregate([{
            $unwind : "$firstArray"
        }, {
            $project : {
                _id : 1,
                firstArray : 1,
                isNotEmpty : {
                    $size : "$firstArray.secondArray"
                }
            }
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : "$_id",
                isNotEmpty : {
                    $sum : "$isNotEmpty"
                },
                firstArray : {
                    $push : "$firstArray"
                }
            }
        }, {
            $match : {
                "isNotEmpty" : 0
            }
        }

    ])
```

Any comments welcome

Comment: I got this: aggregate failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: invalid operator '$size'",
        "code" : 15999,
        "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:898

Comment: what version of mongo do you use?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.4.14